# Cannot adopt WebKit protocols

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject <WebFrameLoadDelegate> {
WebView *webView;
}
```

> cannot find protocol declaration for 'WebFrameLoadDelegate'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WebFrameLoadDelegate` is a [informal protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-TPXREF147) - it is declared as a category of `NSObject`. To use it you need to declare required methods in class interface and implement them.

> When used to declare a protocol, a
>   category interface doesn’t have a
>   corresponding implementation. Instead,
>   classes that implement the protocol
>   declare the methods again in their own
>   interface files and define them along
>   with other methods in their
>   implementation files.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from Apple Developer Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003828

...However, depending on the content being loaded, some of the other methods defined in this protocol may be invoked multiple times. **All the methods in this protocol are optional.**

So the before answer is not correct in the sense of that it is not necessary to implement all the methods.